# Label moving after optimization is turned on in gcc

Tags: c, optimization, gcc, x86, label

I have a strange problem after turning on level 1 optimization in gcc. What I do is save the label and jmp back to it from a different function later.

```
void
UMS__suspend_procr( VirtProcr *animatingPr )
{ 
   animatingPr->nextInstrPt = &&ResumePt;


   [Some Code and inline volatile asm]

   ResumePt:
   return;
```

}

I do some of these jumps and they all work fine.
The problem is that when I turn on O1 it does not save the right label address. Instead it does this:

```
804b14e:       8b 45 08                mov    0x8(%ebp),%eax
804b151:       c7 40 14 4e b1 04 08    movl   $0x804b14e,0x14(%eax)
804b158:       8b 55 08                mov    0x8(%ebp),%edx
```

So the program is jumping back even before the assignment.

Comment: Are you aware that taking the address of a label is a non-standard language extension?  And therefore totally non-portable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This code is not valid GNU C. To begin with, computed gotos (`&&label`) are a feature specific to GNU C, not part of the C language, but that's ok if you're using GNU C. However, the only place they're valid in GNU C is with a `goto` statement. You cannot use the pointer with inline asm as an indirect jump/call destination, because adjusting the stack frame is up to the compiler, and the current logical view of the stack frame from the point of the inline asm and the label destination might not match. With an explicit `goto` statement, the compiler can patch this up, but with asm it can't even tell it's happening.

As for the bigger picture, if you're writing code like this, you should really rethink some of your assumptions. There's certainly a better way to accomplish what you want.

Comment: Yes I'm aware that this is only a part of GNU C. The stack is fine I always jump back into the same functions and everytime I jmp I save my stackframe and invalidate all registers. Is it possible, that this is a reason for the moving label?

Comment: The stack is not fine. The compiler is free to adjust it *whenever and however it wants* and that is outside of your control. You are simply not allowed to do whatever you're trying to do. It if "works", it's pure luck, and it **can and will** break.

Comment: @merten: Regardless of the stack, you say "What I do is save the label and jmp back to it from a different function later." -- well, the GCC documentation very explicitly states: "You may not use this mechanism to jump to code in a different function. If you do that, totally unpredictable things will happen."  (See the [recent version here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.0/gcc/Labels-as-Values.html); exactly the same language has been there for a very long time.)